# La différence entre la voix passive et se faire

Tags: passif

J'aimerais savoir s'il y a une différence entre "se faire" et "la voix passive" ?

Par exemple, quelle est la différence entre les deux phrases suivantes :

> Elle s'est fait aviser
>
> Elle a été avisée

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Se voir* et *être* partage la fonction de diathèse passive, mais on peut dégager quelques différences dans leur fonctionnement et dans leur usage :

**1. Le complément transformable en sujet**

Le passif en *être* ne peut promouvoir qu'un objet direct en sujet alors que celui en *se faire* est également compatible avec les objets indirects:

- Elle **le** poursuit -> "il est poursuivi" ou "il se fait poursuivre"
- Elle **lui** court après -> "il se fait courir après (par elle)" mais jamais *"il est couru après"

Une troisième construction passive existe, presque exclusivement utilisée avec des verbes  de don, utilisant *se voir* comme auxiliaire. Elle ne sert elle qu'à promouvoir des objets indirects, récipients du don : "On lui remet un prix" -> "Il s'est vu remettre un prix"

**2. La nature du sujet du verbe passif**

Le passif en *se faire* est utilisé de préférence avec des sujets animés, tandis que celui en *être* ne présente pas une telle restriction :

- "J'ai retrouvé ton arbre" -> "ton arbre a été retrouvé" mais rarement ?"ton arbre s'est fait retrouver"
- "J'ai viré ton fils" -> "ton fils a été viré" et "ton fils s'est fait virer" fonctionne aussi bien l'un que l'autre

**3. Le caractère positif ou négatif de l'action du verbe**

Finalement, le passif en *se faire* n'est que rarement utilisé lorsque l'action verbe a un effet bénéfique pour le sujet.

"J'ai retrouvé ton fils" -> "ton fils a été retrouvé" marche beaucoup mieux que ?"ton fils s'est fait retrouver"

La même phrase utilisée avec *être* ou avec *se faire* peut d'ailleurs avoir un sens différent, puisque *se faire* implique que l'action n'était pas la bienvenue :

- "J'ai été reconnu par mon chef" : compatible avec les deux sens de reconnaître (identifier comme une personne en particulier et exprimer de la reconnaissance pour quelqu'un) et dans le premier cas n'implique pas forcément que le sujet essayait de se cacher
- "Je me suis fait reconnaître par mon chef" : uniquement compatible avec le premier sens de reconnaître et avec le sous-entendu que le sujet essayait de ne pas être remarqué.

Answer (score 2):

On affirmera d'abord que les deux **phrases** :

*Elle s'est fait aviser* et *Elle a été avisée* sont bien **toutes deux** à la voix passive. Il s'agit de ce que l'on peut appeler un **passif syntaxique**.

(La voix active correspondante étant du style : *Machin l'a avisée*)

La différence entre les deux réside dans le fait que dans la seconde, le sens passif est rendu par un **verbe** à la forme passive. (c'est ce que l'on peut appeler un **passif morphologique**) alors que dans la première on peut considérer que la forme du **verbe** n'est pas passive.

Ce qui importe dans le rendu d'une **phrase** passive (par rapport à la forme active) ce n'est pas tant que le **verbe** soit ou non à la forme passive, c'est la permutation des syntagmes nominaux : Le complément d'objet devient le sujet et le sujet devient l'agent.

En règle générale, quand on veut rendre une voix passive avec un verbe actif, c'est que l'on souhaite mettre l'**accent sur le processus**, l'action. Alors que passif syntaxique + passif morphologique, surtout au passé composé, on énonce un un fait.

*Elle a été rappelée à l'ordre* : Bon! C'est un fait! C'est passé!

*Elle s'est fait rappeler à l'ordre* : Houlaa!! La remontrance fut longue, ça a saigné vilain et pas que cinq minutes... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Il  existe une différence de contexte; la tournure  passive peut impliquer un contexte préparatoire où la personne avisée a fait des démarches qui ont résulté en un avis.
Au contraire, la tournure à valeur passive ne présuppose aucun contexte de relation directe mais un contexte d'anormalité qui est la cause de l'action rapportée par la tournure à valeur passive.

- La direction de l'entreprise avait fait le nécessaire pour régulariser sa situation envers l'administration locale ; elle a été avisée rapidement de ses droits dans le domaine de la distribution. (*Il me semble que l'on n'emploiera pas naturellement « **s'est fait aviser** » dans le présent cas*.)
- C'était une firme aux pratiques peu communes, dont les responsables ne se souciaient pas assez de légalité ; certains présageaient qu'il y aurait bientôt des problèmes ; cela n'a pas tardé, la direction s'est fait aviser dernièrement de la nécessité de préciser aux autorités le statut d'une partie de leur personnel étranger. (*On pourrait aussi utiliser « **a été avisée** »*.)

- Je ne savait pas trop bien et j'ai demandé au surveillant, par qui il m'a été dit que le travail en groupe n'était toléré que  dans le silence absolu. (*On ne dira pas aussi naturellement « **je me suis fait dire** », à moins qu'il existe un contexte de remontrance, de reproche, comme si on était sensé savoir cela, par exemple.*)
- Jeanine et ses camarades, trop bruyants dans leur travail, se sont fait dire qu'ils perturbaient l'étude. (*« Il a été dit à Jeanine et ses camarades qu'ils perturbaient l'étude. » ne reflète pas l'idée de reproche que l'on trouve dans la tournure à valeur passive, elle est comparativement ineffective en ce sens-là.*)

L'utilisation de la tournure à valeur passive implique parfois un contexte non neutre,  qui peut être un contexte de  dénigration, de rejet, au contraire de la tournure passive.

- Un délégué avait fait quelques propositions à ce sujet ; il s'est fait dire que lorsque l'on aurait besoin de suggestions on savait où le trouver. (*« Il lui a été dit » implique que le locuteur considère l'acte de communication qu'il rapporte comme étant plus neutre, comme n'ayant pas nécessairement de signification dans le sens de révéler envers le délégué  une attitude particulière de qui lui répond.*)