# Un verbe pronominal peut-il avoir un objet qui n'est pas soi ?

Tags: pronoms, verbes-pronominaux, complément-cod

Je suis troublé par l'ajout des pronoms objets comme ***le*** ou ***la*** à des verbes pronominaux. Dans ***se la raconter*** ou bien ***se le faire*** ; à quoi réfère *la*, à quoi réfère *le* ?

On peut prendre ces phrases comme exemples :

> Il se l'ai fait dérober il y a 2 ans.

> Toujours, il se la raconte.

Je voudrais plus spécifiquement parler d'expressions non figées.

Ce serait bien de pouvoir comprendre le sens de ces expressions relativement au sens du chaque mot.

Comment: Je ne suis pas certaine de pouvoir mettre *se la raconter* et *se le faire* sur le même plan. *Se la raconter*  est une expression où effectivement on a du mal à identifier *la* à quelque chose de précis (c'est même pas « une histoire » parce que « se la raconter » ça peut aussi se dire « se la péter », « se la jouer », et toutes ces expressions synonymes sont argotiques), et *la* reste *la* (jamais avec *le* à ma connaissance.)

Comment: Par contre je pourrais dire *je vais me le faire*, ou *je vais me la faire* où *le* ou *la* représente effectivement un l'individu que je veux « démolir ». À moins  que ne penses à l'expression *on ne me la fait pas* ( : c'est pas à moi qu'on va faire croire ça) , où effectivement *la* s'est pas substituable. Tu peux préciser ?

Comment: Désole d’avoir être assez flous. Je voulais plus spécifiquement parler des expressions pas figé.

Comment: Ca serait bien quand meme de savoir le sens que ces expressions traduisent par rapport au sens du chaque mot.

Comment: Quand je vois juste *se le faire* ou *se la raconter* je pense tout de suite aux expressions argotiques. Pour être clair il faudrait que tu emploies ces mots dans des phrases, ce sera plus simple à comprendre ce que demandes.

Comment: Oui, on est tout à fait dans l'argot.

Comment: @None je pense que la question est sir l'utilisation de pronoms d'objet avec des verbes pronominaux: peut-on avoir un pronom COD ou COI, et à quoi correspond dans ces cas le pronom réfléchi? C'est ma interprétation de cette question.

Comment: @RogerVadim Oui exact ! Même si les pronoms ne font pas une référence explicite à un objet spécifique, généralement de quoi s'agit-t-il ?

Comment: @YohannesTimket les pronoms réfléchis font la référence au sujet (*Je lave mon enfant.* vs. *Je me lave.*) Par contre, quand il s'agit de plusieurs pronoms, il y a un ordre spécifique dans les formes bon-reflechis, dependant de personne, de pronoms COD/COI, etc. Je ne sais pas, comment ça s'applique aux verbes réfléchis - peut-être en français *se* est toujours COD: *Je me lave.* = *je lave moi-même.*, mais *je me lave les mains* -> *Je me les lave.* = *Je les lave à moi.*- ce n'est pas vraiment une form réfléchis. (Mes exemple ne sont pas forcément le français authentique.)

Comment: Les structures de tes deux phrases sont différentes. Ton premier exemple sera facile à expliquer (se faire + infinitif) mais pour le deuxième on manque de contexte. *Se la raconter* est un idiome et j'ai du mal à trouver comment sortir de cet idiome.

Answer (score 3):

> Est-ce que ton frère peut me prêter **son vélo** ?
> Non, il se **l**'ai fait dérober il y a deux ans.

Dans cette phrase **se faire + infinitif**  est une forme de voix passive<sup>1</sup>.  Le complément d'objet direct **l** est identifiable d'après le contexte :  il s'est fait dérober quoi ? → **son vélo**.

De même :

> — Est-ce que tu peux me prêter ta voiture ? — Non, je me la suis fait voler hier.

Pour moi « il se la raconte » sans contexte, c'est l'expression argotique *se la raconter*. C'est toujours un verbe pronominal, et donc bien sûr *se* se modifie si on conjugue le verbe (je me la raconte, tu te...) mais *la* ne remplace rien et reste *la*. Avec un peu d'imagination je pourrais dire que *la* est mis pour histoire parce que ce qu'on raconte le plus ce sont des histoires... mais c'est une interprétation tout à fait personnelle. Une expression synonyme de se la raconter est *se la péter*, et on pourrait penser que *la* est mis pour tête (qui va péter/éclater tellement je suis orgueilleux) mais encore une fois c'est personnel.

On peut bien sûr trouver un contexte où « il se la raconte » ne serait pas argotique, c'est à dire où raconter serait employé dans son sens propre. On a forcément le mot *histoire* pas loin. J'ai trouvé deux exemples :

> Il se la raconte cette *histoire*, il vérifie ses incohérences, la modifie. **Se *la* raconte** une nouvelle fois. Puis, il laisse décanter.
> Il se laisse aller, raconte *l'histoire* à Yvan autant qu'**il se *la* raconte**, une nouvelle fois.

Si on avait histoires (pluriel)  on aurait *se **les** raconte*.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Voir [cette leçon](https://leflepourlescurieux.fr/voix-passive-une-autre-maniere-de-sexprimer-b1/) pour la formation et les réponses à [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/38438/358) pour une analyse plus poussée de la structure.</sup>